# How to fit banner widget with its parent?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, user-interface, banner

[image]

My parent is a container inside of that I have a card.

I would like to fit my banner with card view on the top left.

```
Container(
child :Card(
child:Banner(
message: 'hello',
location: BannerLocation.topEnd,
child:myWidget()
)
)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your Banner widget with ClipRect

```
ClipRect(
          child: Banner(
            message: "hello",
           )
)
```